# При получении постов с базы данных mysql не отображается кириллица

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добавляю записи в таблицу базы данных через запрос и через phpmyadmin, в самой таблице кириллица и латиница нормально отображаются, но при получении и выводе постов на сервере кириллические символы отображаются знаками вопроса. Кодировка базы данных и страниц на сервере одна и та же utf8. Кто знает в чем проблема и как её решить? Система Linux

index.php

```
<?php require_once "templates/header.php"; ?>

    <?php
        require_once "db.php";

        $result = $conn->query("SELECT `title`, `text`, `date` FROM news");

    ?>

    <section id="news" class="news">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="news__wrapper">

                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

                <div class="news__item">
                    <div class="news__item-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <h2><?= $row['title']; ?></h2>
                        <span><?= $row['date']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news__item-content">
                        <?= $row['text']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php require_once "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

db.php

```
<?php

        /* Connecting to database */

        $host     = "127.0.0.1"; //host ip
        $username = "admin"; //username of database
        $password = "123";  //db user password
        $database = "news";  //database name

        //establishing connecting to db
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

        //if something went wrong during connection to db
        if ($conn->connect_error)
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    ?>
```

Comment: Это кажется самый популярный вопрос по php и MySQL =) Кодировку общения php и MySQL установите

Answer (score 1):

Возможно нужно указать кодировку)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database); mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
```